# How do I view the HTTP response to an ActiveResource request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeresource

I am trying to debug an ActiveResource call that is not working.

What's the best way to view the HTTP response to the request ActiveResource is making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy.  Just look at the response that comes back.  :)

Two options:

- You have the source file on your computer.  Edit it.  Put a `puts response.inspect` at the appropriate place.  Remember to remove it.
- Ruby has open classes.  Find the right method and redefine it to do exactly what you want, or use aliases and call chaining to do this.  There's probably a method that returns the response -- grab it, print it, and then return it.

Here's a silly example of the latter option.

```
# Somewhere buried in ActiveResource:
class Network
  def get
    return get_request
  end

  def get_request
    "I'm a request!"
  end
end

# Somewhere in your source files:
class Network
  def print_request
    request = old_get_request
    puts request
    request
  end
  alias :old_get_request :get_request
  alias :get_request :print_request
end
```

Imagine the first class definition is in the ActiveRecord source files.  The second class definition is in your application somewhere.

```
$ irb -r openclasses.rb 
>> Network.new.get
I'm a request!
=> "I'm a request!"
```

You can see that it prints it and then returns it.  Neat, huh?

(And although my simple example doesn't use it since it isn't using Rails, check out `alias_method_chain` to combine your alias calls.)

Answer (score 14):

Monkey patch the connection to enable Net::HTTP debug mode. See https://gist.github.com/591601  -  I wrote it to solve precisely this problem. Adding this gist to your rails app will give you `Net::HTTP.enable_debug!` and `Net::HTTP.disable_debug!` that you can use to print debug info.

Net::HTTP debug mode is insecure and shouldn't be used in production, but is extremely informative for debugging.

Answer (score 4):

Add a new file to `config/initializers/` called `'debug_connection.rb'` with the following content:

```
class ActiveResource::Connection
  # Creates new Net::HTTP instance for communication with
  # remote service and resources.
  def http
    http = Net::HTTP.new(@site.host, @site.port)
    http.use_ssl = @site.is_a?(URI::HTTPS)
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE if http.use_ssl
    http.read_timeout = @timeout if @timeout
    # Here's the addition that allows you to see the output
    http.set_debug_output $stderr
    return http
  end
end
```

This will print the whole network traffic to $stderr.

Answer (score 3):

I like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) because you can start it listening on the web browser client end (usually your development machine) and then do a page request.  Then you can find the HTTP packets, right click and "Follow Conversation" to see the HTTP with headers going back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

This only works if you also control the server:

Follow the server log and fish out the URL that was called:

```
Completed in 0.26889 (3 reqs/sec) | Rendering: 0.00036 (0%) | DB: 0.02424 (9%) | 200 OK [http://localhost/notifications/summary.xml?person_id=25738]
```

and then open that in Firefox. If the server is truely RESTful (ie. stateless) you will get the same response as ARes did.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way is to use a traffic sniffer.

(Which would totally work...except in my case the traffic I want to see is encrypted. D'oh!)

Comment: Charles’ HTTPS proxy is super useful for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Or my method of getting into things when I don't know the exact internals is literally just to throw in a "debugger" statement, start up the server using "script/server --debugger" and then step through the code until I'm at the place I want, then start some inspecting right there in IRB.....that might help (hey Luke btw)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [TCPFlow](http://www.circlemud.org/jelson/software/tcpflow/) here to watch the traffic going over the wire, rather than patching my app to output it.

Answer (score -1):

the firefox plugin live http headers (http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) is great for this.  Or you can use a website tool like http://www.httpviewer.net/